# Trying to create import module for Python (for RPi GPIO)

Tags: python, module, raspberry-pi

I am new to Python. I am trying to create a fake GPIO module for my Raspberry Pi that uses PWM motors so that my interpreter (using Visual Studio Code) can understand it and pass it without error.

This is what I wanted to achieve:

```
#Motor.py

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.PWM(16,100).start(0)
```

This is the fake module I have attempted to create after attempting to learn the basic way how python handles modules

```
#RPi/GPIO.py
#(RPi folder has an empty __init__.py file along with the GPIO.py file)

BOARD = 1
IN = 1
OUT = 1

def setmode(a):
   print(a)
def setup(a):
   print(a)
def output(a):
   print(a)

def PWM(a, b):
   print(a)
   def start(c):
      print(c)
```

The error I have gotten shows like this:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'`

I do not know how to properly create modules where it could work with multiple periods.
How should I fix it so that it would achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GPIO.PWM` is a class - and `start` is a member function of that class.

So you'll need to look at how classes are constructed using the `__init__()` method, and how member functions work.

Here is an example of the PWM class you'll need to create:

```
class PWM:

    def __init__(self, channel, frequency):

        print(f"PWM({channel},{frequency})");

    def start(self, duty_cycle):

        print(f"PWM.start({duty_cycle})")
```

So looking at `GPIO.PWM(16,100).start(0)` - this would first construct a PWM object by calling the `PWM __init__()` method - and then call the `start()` method on that object.

You can also split this into two calls if you need the PWM object. i.e.

```
motor_pwm = GPIO.PWM(16.100)
motor_pwm.start(0)
```

If that makes more sense?

Comment: Yes! It worked. I hadn't learned Class in Python, but after a quick search, I understood. This will help me a lot when it comes to organizing my codes. Thank you very much.